# Searching by DateTime in Sitecore 7 Update-1

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7

I am attempting perform a query using the Sitecore 7 search API. The query contains a number of DateTime where clauses. In the example below, EffectiveFrom and EffectiveTo are DateTime properties.

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var schedules = context.GetQueryable<ScheduleSearchResultItem>()
                           .Where(item => item.EffectiveFrom <= DateTime.Now)
                           .Where(item => item.EffectiveTo >= DateTime.Now);

    foreach (var schedule in schedules)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

`ScheduleSearchResultItem` inherits from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem` and looks like the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Search result item for event schedules
/// </summary>
public class ScheduleSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// EffectiveFrom field
    /// </summary>
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter))]
    [IndexField("effectivefrom")]
    public DateTime EffectiveFrom { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// EffectiveTo field
    /// </summary>
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter))]
    [IndexField("effectiveto")]
    public DateTime EffectiveTo { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

This was working with the initial release of Sitecore 7, however, it now throws a **"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."** error in Sitecore 7 Update-1.

I have tried dozens of index configurations, as well as adding and removing the `IndexFieldDateTimeValueConverter` attribute on my `ScheduleSearchResultItem`. I have confirmed via Luke that these items do contain dates in yyyyMMdd format. That said, not all of my items have *effectivefrom* and *effectiveto* fields.

Anyone else experiencing the same behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a localized issue. The `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Indexes.config` file somehow made it's way into my Includes folder during the upgrade process. I am not using Solr, and removing this file fixed the issue.

Comment: This just happened to me as well. The problem is that it is not well defined in the Sitecore upgrade instructions. If you're not paying full attention then you will add the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Indexes.config file along with the other updated config files. Thanks!